# Dealloc ContainedViewController inside block

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I would like to remove a contained view controller after animating it off the screen... however in the implementation below dealloc is never called... Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? If I add `commentsTableViewController = nil;` at the end of the completion block I get... `variable not assignable missing __block type specifier`

I'm lost... this seems to have only come around with the latest version of XCode

```
-(void)commentsTableViewControllerReadyForDismiss:(id)sender
{
    CommentsTableViewController *commentsTableViewController = sender;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4f
                        delay:0.0f
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState | UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^{

                     commentsTableViewController.view.center = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x, self.view.bounds.size.height + commentsTableViewController.view.frame.size.height/2);
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        [commentsTableViewController willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
        [commentsTableViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
        [commentsTableViewController removeFromParentViewController];

    }];
}
```

Comment: Make commentsTableViewController a `weak` property

Comment: @Paulw11 `__weak CommentsTableViewController *commentsTableViewController = sender;` ? No joy if so...

Comment: It helps now that you have shown the full method.  The local variable `commentsTableViewController` won't be a problem because it will be released when the method exits.  You must be holding a strong reference to this view controller somewhere else.

Comment: Then declare `commentsTableViewController` with the __block specifier - then you can assign nil

Comment: @Paulw11 You were right, I held onto `commentsTableViewController` in the animation block..